# PSA: Debugging Woes: Forgotten debug statements in code

Tags: debugging, error-handling

When debugging, one often adds code to print the problem to the screen. I will use Website programming, and php as an example.

So I was integrating PHPmailer into my site. I have an include file where I enter my hostname, username, password, and port. These are defined into phps scope:

```
$port = 587;  // Port for TLS
define("EMAIL_PORT", $port);
```

Then I was debugging this and added: `echo EMAIL_HOSTNAME;` in my sendmail.php.
It was late at night, I got everything working, and went to bed. The next day I wanted to create my own response for my javascript callback, using this pattern:

```
if ($condition){ 
        $r['status'] = 'success';
} else { 
    $r['status'] = 'Failed: Error:' . $errorResponse;
}
echo json_encode($r);
```

So my expected response is `{"status":"success"}`. However, I forgot about the debug echo statement, so my response was `smtp.google.com{"status":"success"}`. Suffice it to say, took me a while to remember about adding the echo statement the night before trying to stay awake to get email working.

After researching to turn off all debugging in PHPmailer, I still thought it was the mail object echoing the hostname. Finally after wasting an hour I happened to spot it in my code!

TLDR:
The point of this post is a PSA: When using debug statements, don't just echo a variable value. Echo (or alert or whatever language your using has) some details as well. My echo statement should have been:

```
echo "Debug from sendmail.php: hostname is " . EMAIL_HOSTNAME;
```

Comment: You would be better off using logging than outputting. This will entirely avoid differing output behavior once in production. This isn't really on topic for SO and the tags you chose we kind of spamming those languages as this isn't an issue for them.